# How to have a title fade out only once on web page (java script class add)

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
 const element = document.getElementById('title');
 const element2=document.getElementById('subtitle');
 if(window.scrollY>600){
            element.classList.add('fadeout1');
            element2.classList.add('fadeout1');
           
          }
```

```css
.fadeout{
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;

  transition: visibility 0s .5s, opacity 1s linear;
}

#text12{
  text-align:center;
  overflow:none;
  transition:.4s;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:5;
  color:#FFD800;
  font-weight:400;
  font-size:25px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity:1;
  visibility:visible;
  top:20%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-family:neuzeit-grotesk-extra-conden,sans-serif;

}
```

```html
<div id="text12">
 <h2 id="subtitle" class="title1"style="font-weight: 300">Los Angeles
  </h2>
<h1 id="title" class="title2" style="font-weight: 500;letter-spacing:15px;font-size:150px;">RAFAEL</h1>
  <h2 id="subtitle" class="sub"style="font-weight: 300">Creative Direction, Photography, moving image
  </h2>
  
</div>
```

I have a site that has a title then fades after scrolling through using java script and adding a class "fadeout" to the ID of title when the user scrolls past 600 pixels or so. It works fine and as intended on the home page but I want it to not show up even after clicking on other pages from my navbar and returning back. Right now the user can click on a diff page from navbar, return to homepage and title will pop up again. Is there any way using methods related to what I have implemented to make the fadeout class stick permanently to the title? the fade out has visibility:0 and opacity:0 so I would want those characteristics to stay on the title as long as user is on the page. The navbar links are just general html css href links. Any insight on possibilities or ways to go about this would be great! Thank you for your time!

Comment: I have attached my code now.

Comment: You could save the script into its own file, and load that script only on the main page. Alternatively check `window.location.href`, and if that's not the address of the main page, don't add the fade classes to the elements.

Comment: If that script only gets loaded only the main page, It will still start again with the title if you go to a different page and return. I want it to fade out and never come back regardless if I switch pages on the site and come back. but the code just resets and checks if user scroll below 600 again and notices it is so page title will display again

Comment: For that you'd need a permanent marker telling you the page has been loaded earlier. Maybe put that into localStorage or create a cookie. Alternatively call the main page with a specific search string when loaded for the first time, and check the search string in the function.

Comment: Thank you! I looked into local storage and how it works and found a way to implement it to get what I need using sessionStorage.